# addEventListener not fires change event of element

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have selectbox, after page loads selected item changed(via ajax call) and I need to catch this event, so I added this;

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                document.getElementById("mySelectBox").addEventListener("change", function() {
                    debugger
                }, true);
            })
```

and expected when selected item changed async it triggers and step into the function inside listener but its not...

This can be solved using setTimeOut function, but its ugly and as you know there is possible side effects.

```
setTimeout(function(){*business logic*},2000)
```

Comment: @Merigold lol, I just skipped content of BL to make post clear

Comment: Is it a part of the page that you load dynamically, by using AJAX for example?

Comment: @VictorHerasmePerez yes, this is why your answer not works :(

Comment: Then you should use the `on()` method. I will edit the answer

Comment: I dont think it would work as well, it just triigers only element changed by UI not async action

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding elements dynamically by using AJAX, use the `on()` method. Let's say there is a div (`the-parent-div`) which contains `#mySelectBox`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('the-parent-div').on('change', '#mySelectBox', function(){
         //Your actions go here
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:**
You might be referring to the async nature of ajax calls. See this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) and the accepted [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/9015852):

> .......
>   The **A** in [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) stands for [**asynchronous**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/asynchronous) . That means
>   sending the request (or rather receiving the response) is taken out of
>   the normal execution flow. In your example, `$.ajax` returns
>   immediately and the next statement, `return result;`, is executed
>   before the function you passed as `success` callback was even called.
>   .....

Comment: While they could bind the event listener using jQuery, that wouldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing ) at the end of the code

Comment: Questions where the problem is caused by a typo are off-topic. They should be closed and not answered. When you have more reputation you'll be able to comment on any question and vote to close them. In the meantime, please don't *answer* off-topic questions.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have a typo in your code. You forgot the `)` at the end, but I assume that is a transcription error.

The change is event is fired when the user interface is used to change the form control.

You said "when selected item changed async" which implies that you are changing the form control using JavaScript and not by a user interaction event.

This won't trigger the event.

You can either call the function manually…

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     function changefunction() {
         debugger
     }
     document.getElementById("mySelectBox").addEventListener("change", changefunction, true);
     do_something_to_change_mySelectBox();
     changefunction.call(document.getElementById("mySelectBox"));
 });
```

… or make use of jQuery's event abstraction features. This would require that you bind the event handle using jQuery though.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#mySelectBox").on("change", function() {
         debugger
     });
     do_something_to_change_mySelectBox();
     $("#mySelectBox").trigger("change");

 });
```

Comment: Oops. Typo. Fixed. And live demo: http://jsbin.com/xelasutade/1/edit?html,js,output (and make sure your debugging tools are open!).